# Bool query with fuzziness in elastic search java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I am trying to implement the selection of users from a given college and name. Here the name has fuzzy query.
Following is the query in elastic search (v5.1.2) which gives me the desired result. But gives an error in Java

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool": {
            "must" : [{
                "match": {
                    "collegeAccountCode": "DIT"
                }
            },
            { 
                "match": {
                    "name" : {
                        "query": "Rahul",
                        "fuzziness" : "AUTO"
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to implement this using following java API (v5.1.2)

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", studentName).fuzziness())
            .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("collegeAccountCode", AccountId));
```

But I get an error saying :

```
"The method must(QueryBuilder) in the type BoolQueryBuilder is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Fuzziness)"
```

How to fix this error or is there any other way to implement this query ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is, that method `fuziness()` without parameter return the current `Fuzziness`, which is obviously isn't expected by `must()`, and you need to do something like this:

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name", "Rahul").fuzziness(Fuzziness.AUTO))
                .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("collegeAccountCode", "DIT"));
```

A piece of code, explaining the problem a bit more:

```
 /** Sets the fuzziness used when evaluated to a fuzzy query type. Defaults to "AUTO". */
    public MatchQueryBuilder fuzziness(Object fuzziness) {
        this.fuzziness = Fuzziness.build(fuzziness);
        return this;
    }

    /**  Gets the fuzziness used when evaluated to a fuzzy query type. */
    public Fuzziness fuzziness() {
        return this.fuzziness;
    }
```

You called, the second method, while you need to call the first one.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I never thought this could be the problem. You explained it quite well.

Comment: Also it says default AUTO so I assumed I don't have to provide any arguments.